# Explain articles usage in the example

Tags: articles

Here is a piece of text:

> Since Dapper has been in production and operating at large scale for
>   years now, we decided it would be most appropriate to focus this paper
>   on what Dapper’s deployment has taught us, how our design decisions
>   played out, and in what ways it has been most useful. The value of
>   Dapper as a platform for  ***XXX development*** of performance analysis
>   tools, as much as a monitoring tool in itself, is one of a few
>   unexpected outcomes we can identify in ***a retrospective assessment***.

Which articles would you place before two words in bold (`development` and `retrospective assessment`)?

Do not they mean/imply particular and very specific development (that has led to the developing of specific and well-known tools)? Is so, should not `the development` be there?

On the other hand, does not `a retrospective assessment` mean literally just any retrospective assessment ever made by anyone?

Comment: xxx=the or none; The dapper team have conducted a retrospective assessment which has a surprising outcome. It is not just any but a specific assessment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without "of performance analysis tools", you would use no article:

> The value of Dapper as a platform for development, as much as...

But adding "of performance analysis tools" makes the development specific, so use *the*:

> The value of Dapper as a platform for **the** development *of performance analysis tools*, as much as...

I would say that "retrospective assessment" is not specific in itself (it is not defined), so use *a*. If it was a specific assessment defined elsewhere, then use *the*.